# HTTP HEAD request giving ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END error with node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a health check route for my application which we use to check the application's health, it's a `GET` route but we send `HTTP HEAD` call to the same route but I am getting `ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END` error. When digging into that I found out whenever I try to send response data for type `HEAD` call this error comes but couldn't find the actual reason for the same. Can someone explain why it's behaving this way? The sample code is given below.

Code with error, it's giving error even with `res.json` and `res.send`

```
router.get('/health', function (req, res) {
    res.send({
        message: "working great!!!"
    });
    res.end();
});
```

Update 1 -> After removing `res.send`, it's working fine, but still interested to know why by using `res.send`, it's giving the error. in `HTTP HEAD` call, client is working as expected it's ignoring `response body` but why on `sever side`, we are getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `res.end()` it might solve the issue

And you can try this

```
router.route("/health").get(function (req, res) {
    res.send({
        message: "working great!!!"
    });
    
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes, after removing ```res.send``` it worked, do you have any idea why this is the case? why by using ```res.send```, it's throwing the error?

Comment: `'res.end` end the requests and `res.send` takes sometimes to stringfiy the responses and when `res.send` try to send the response it not find the request object and it gives this error